# Adding class attribute to password field not working in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view

I've just started learning ruby on rails recently.

I've login form like this,

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="field">
                <%= label_tag :email %><br />
                <%= text_field_tag :email, params[:email], :class => 'form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="field">
                <%= label_tag :password %><br />
                <%= password_field_tag :password, :class =>'form-control' %>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm just trying to add bootstrap class `form-control` to email and password field but some thing went wrong, class value appeared at input field of password.

And I've got view like this,

[image: login view]

The question might be stupid, any help suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v5.1.3/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-password_field_tag), the second parameter of `password_field_tag` method is value, so you should set it in order to set third parameter, where you can set the class:

```
<%= password_field_tag :password, nil, class: 'form-control' %>
```